# node.js returning only specific data from a http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, http, request

I'm attempting to use the Destiny 2 API in a discord chatbot I have been writing. Right now I just want it to return my player id by sending a request to the address designated in the API. I can successfully do this but it returns more information than I need. How do I just return the 'membershipId'?

The body of this request returns:

```
{
    "Response": [
        {
            "membershipType": 4,
            "membershipId": "4611686018470641209",
            "displayName": "LazyBrain#2918"
        }
    ],
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData": {}
}
```

Code:

```
    case 'stats':
    let options = {
        url: HOST + '/SearchDestinyPlayer/4/LazyBrain%232918/',
        headers: {
            'X-API-Key': config.key
        }
    };

    request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        let json = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body)['Response']);
        console.log(json);
    });
```

But with the above code I have narrowed it down to:

```
[
    {
        "membershipType": 4,
        "membershipId": "4611686018470641209",
        "displayName": "LazyBrain#2918"
    }
]
```

I'm not entirely sure if I'm going about this the right way though.

Comment: If u want member id just do `json[0]["membershipId"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
var raw = JSON.parse(body);
var membershipID = raw.Response[0].membershipId;
```

Without minding the other JSON Data/Keys

**Example:**

```js
var body = '{"Response":[{"membershipType":4,"membershipId":"4611686018470641209","displayName":"LazyBrain#2918"}],"ErrorCode":1,"ThrottleSeconds":0,"ErrorStatus":"Success","Message":"Ok","MessageData":{}}';

var raw = JSON.parse(body);
var membershipID = raw.Response[0].membershipId;

console.log(membershipID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-json) and use dot notation to access membershipId.

For example:

```
req.body.membershipId
```

I am unsure of the entirety of your code so the above is unlikely to work first try, you need the request object which should be given on a GET request.

Based on your question it looks like you have the membershipId inside an array, so use `json[0].membershipId` but do not use `stringify` on json beforehand, or use `JSON.parse(body)["Response"][0].membershipId`

Comment: Not entirely sure if this would've worked as the above worked fine and I haven't used body-parser before. But thank you for the quick response all the same.